# Match last regex pattern in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am coding a script in Perl and need to extract some information from a text file.

This is what my code looks like - the string values are made up but represent all possible string variations.

```
my @alpha = ("abcdefgh(i) jklmno(pqrs3), uvwxyz", 
             "abcdefghi jklmn(opq1st), uvwxyz",
             "abcdefghi jklmn(o_q(1s3)), uvwxyz",
             "abcdef(gh)i jklmno(pq(1s3)), uvwxyz");

foreach my $line (@alpha){
    if ($line =~ /\((.*\(?.*\)?)\),/){
    print $1
    }
}
```

I am trying to capture the large text between the last set of parenthesis (or brackets for us British English speakers).
Please note I am using the "dot" operator since I want to match anything, text, numbers, or other special characters.

Essentially I want to print out:

```
pqrs3
opq1st
o_q(1s3)
pq(1s3)
```

But I keep getting:

```
 (i) jklmno(pqrs3) <-- not ok
 opq1st <-- this is ok
 opq(1s3) <-- this is also ok
 gh)i jklmno(pq(1s3) <-- not ok
```

What am I doing wrong? or is it even possible to match this way?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you always want the _last outer_ match?  You may need to use a parser here.  Have a look at [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns).

Comment: yes I do, and its not necessary to have a single line of regex. I did try to get everything between the first parenthesis and the last, but that did not work as well.

Comment: One other question: Do you know how many parentheses groups will be present?  It seems to vary at 1-2 in your examples.

Comment: The last string in the array has the maximum number of possible parentheses groups. There aren't any other possible groups present in my data.

Comment: You need to deal with the possible of recursive regex for nested parentheses.

Comment: We British English speakers also use *parentheses*. The difference is that, in the UK, a *bracket* is generally a parenthesis, whereas in American English it is understood to be a square bracket

Comment: @Borodin - the way I know it is Brackets (), square brackets [] and braces {} (or curly braces)... gets confusing talking to coders in the US.

Comment: *“Parentheses”* is fine everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\((?:[^()]|(?1))*\))(?!.*\()
```

You can use `recursive` regex here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/21

Comment: This is one of the most elegant uses of regex I have ever seen. Thank you.
I guess the regex101 link has the description of expression as well ?

Comment: @Sid5427 yes it has :)

Comment: I am a bit confused here ... I am trying to get rid of the outer parenthesis..
(pq(1s3)) to pq(1s3)...

Comment: @Sid5427 you can easily strip the outer `()` from the caputured group

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with given string:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @alpha = ("abcdefgh(i) jklmno(pqrs3), uvwxyz", 
             "abcdefghi jklmn(opq1st), uvwxyz",
             "abcdefghi jklmn(o_q(1s3)), uvwxyz",
             "abcdef(gh)i jklmno(pq(1s3)), uvwxyz");

foreach my $line (@alpha)
{
    if ( $line =~ m/.*\s+\w+\((.*)\),\s+\w+/ )
    {
        print $1, "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
pqrs3
opq1st
o_q(1s3)
pq(1s3)
```

Comment: The spacing you're using as an anchor is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Miller is right - I did not intend to use the spacing as an anchor, but looking at it now - it looks like a good alternative as well.